# Styling depending on content

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, styles

I'm currently trying to write proper style for item displayed as selected in combobox. The reason I'm doing it is, that I have not much control over how ComboBox display the selected item and - for example - on dark background, the item is still displayed black.

I came with the following solution:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyItem" DataType="ComboBoxItem">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="White"/>
</DataTemplate>

<!-- (...) -->

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>

            <!-- ... --> 
            <!-- Displaying currently selected item -->

                 <ContentPresenter Margin="2" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     Name="ContentSite"
                     ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyItem}"
                     Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}" />

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now when the simple `ComboBoxItem` is selected, it is correctly displayed in the ComboBox. On the other hand, if I - for example - display a button with some content, in return I get the text `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle`, what is far from what I want to display.

I would like to use different templates for different data types displayed in the ComboBox - I will be able to customize their appearance. How can I achieve that?

---

**Edit:**

To be perfectly clear, I'm talking about selected (=chosen) ComboBox item in this context:

[image: Selected item in combo box]

(not about the selected ComboBox item *on the ComboBox's list*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are looking for ContentTemplateSelector:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/using-contenttemplateselector/

Take a look at those links.

Comment: Can you please provide a small example how may I embed that ContentTemplateSelector in my DataTemplate?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the links?

Comment: I did, but `ComboBox` doesn't seem to have a `ContentTemplateSelector` property.

Comment: Your items are gonna be placed inside ComboBoxItems. ComboBox is just the name of the control providing ComboBoxItems. ComboBoxItem display the actual data. Therefore ComboBoxItem does have the ContentTemplateSelector property. Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Sure, but I'm not styling the items displayed on the list (actually, styling them depending on type is a lot easier), but the item, which is displayed as selected. This item is displayed in ContentPresenter, which is a part of my ComboBox template. See my edits.

Comment: SelectedItem property is being owned by ComoBox that is true but it holds the value of your item and not of the visual displaying the item. Visual is still the ComboBoxItem which will turn its background color to blue so you notice that it is selected. You could define a Trigger inside the Style for ComoBoxItem and when IsSelected turns into true you can let the Trigger execute futher custom logic such as applying another style to ComboBoxItem.ContentTemplate. You will not need the TemplateSelector if you pick this approach I just described

Comment: You are talking about items displayed on the list, when the `ComboBox` is expanded. I'm talking about the item displayed *inside* `ComboBox` *after* you select one of items on the list.

Comment: When you select an item inside the ComboBox, the ComboBox usually displays the selected one with backgroundcolor blue and futhermore closes itself. So where is then the list of items that you talking about after you already selected one? Its hard to follow you so please could you explain me exactly what is going on. ComboBox cannot display two lists. Do you wish it to display two lists?

Comment: No. I modified my question a little to clarify, what I'm talking about. Though it seem, that `ContentTemplateSelector` worked after all.

Comment: If ContentTemplateSelector worked then feel free to mark the answer or vote up helpful posts. :) If you still have issues let us know about them.

Comment: I already did :) I also included below a helpful piece of code for everyone, who encounters the same problem. I lost half of the day to fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

Right, there are a few different aspects to this question. Firstly, we can get rid of the default selection colours by adding this into the `Resources` section:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
```

Experiment with these settings as two of them define the colour of the text and two set the colour for the background of the selected item. In fact, you can use whatever colours here to provide a quick way to change the selected item colours... without having to go to all of the trouble that you have gone to. But for your example, let's just leave them as `Transparent`.

Ok, so next you want to have a different look for each different data type that appears in the `ComboBox`... this can also be easily achieved. All you need to do is to declare a `DataTemplate` for each type and *do not set the `x:Key` property* so that they will be implicitly applied. Here is a basic example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Type1}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Type2}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Green" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Type3}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Blue" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

If you populated a `ComboBox` with items of these three types with these `DataTemplate`s, then the items would be coloured in `Red`, Green`and`Blue`.

Comment: Are you sure, that you're talking about the same "selected item" I do? I modified my question a little to show, what am I talking about.

Comment: You're right, I did think that you were talking about the *actual* selected item. However, the separate `DataTemplate`s should still work wherever the data type instance is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the solution with `ContentTemplateSelector` for all, who will seek solution for the same problem.

1. Add the following class to your library/application:

   ```
   public class ComboBoxSelectionTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector 
   {

       public DataTemplate TextTemplate 
       {
           get;
           set;
       }

       public DataTemplate ContentTemplate 
       {
           get;
           set;
       }

       public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container) 
       {
           if (item is string)
               return TextTemplate;
           else
               return ContentTemplate;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Define two different DataTemplates:

   ```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextItem">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static vs:VsBrushes.WindowTextKey}}" />
   </DataTemplate>

   <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxOtherItem">
       <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
   </DataTemplate>
   ```
3. Instantiate the selector inside style you want to use it in:

   ```
   <Style.Resources>
       <local:ComboBoxSelectionTemplateSelector ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxOtherItem}" 
                                                TextTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextItem}" x:Key="ContentTemplateSelector" />
   </Style.Resources>
   ```
4. Use it in the `ContentPresenter`:

   ```
   <!-- ... -->
   <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
       <Grid>
           <ContentPresenter ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ContentTemplateSelector}"
                             Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}" />
           <!-- Other items -->
           <Popup ... /> <!-- For displaying ComboBox's list -->
       </Grid>
   ```